# Directory recursive traversal does not go beyond 2 levels in Matlab

Tags: matlab, directory, traversal

The directory recursive traversal does not go beyond 2 levels.
Why is this so?

```
=============================================================


    currentFolderDir = '.'; % pwd
    % path('C:\Users\EI\Documents\MATLAB\OO\Simple Object Creation in Object Oriented');

    depthLevel = 0;
    folderCount = 0;
    fileCount = 0;

    fprintf('=====================================\n');  
    fprintf('Depth level: %d\n', depthLevel); 
    [folderCount, fileCount] = fileDirectoryRecursiveTraversal (currentFolderDir, depthLevel, folderCount, fileCount);

=============================================================




    function [folderCount, fileCount] = fileDirectoryRecursiveTraversal (currentFile, depthLevel, folderCount, fileCount)    

        for i = 1:depthLevel
            fprintf('\t\t');
        end

        fprintf('%s\n', currentFile ); % Print the name of the entry  
        %isdir(currentFile)  % [ERR] can't go beyond level 2
        %pause;

        if (isdir(currentFile)) % Check if it is a directory   
            folderCount = folderCount + 1;
            fprintf('\nThere are %d folders.\n', folderCount);
            pause

            depthLevel = depthLevel + 1;
            fprintf('=====================================\n');  
            fprintf('Depth level: %d\n', depthLevel); 

             % Get a list of all the entries in the directory
             entries = dir(currentFile);

             % entries(1).name = '.'
             % entries(2).name = '..'
             numberOfEntries = length(entries); % including current folder and pointer to folder 1 level up


             % Ensure that the list is not null
             % if( (numberOfEntries - 2) ~= 0 ) % 2: % entries(1).name = '.'; % entries(2).name = '..'
             if(numberOfEntries ~= 2) 
                % Loop over all the entries
                for i = 3:numberOfEntries    
                   % Recursive call to traverse
                   [folderCount, fileCount] = fileDirectoryRecursiveTraversal( entries(i).name, depthLevel, folderCount, fileCount); % i = 3:numberOfEntries   
                end

                fprintf('\nDepth level: %d\n', depthLevel); 
                fprintf('There are %d files.\n\n', fileCount);  
                fileCount = 0;
             else
                % disp('cccccccccccccccccccc')
                fileCount = 0; % empty folder
             end
        else
           fileCount = fileCount + 1; 
           folderCount = 0;
        end    


        folderCount = folderCount - 1;
        depthLevel = depthLevel - 1; % exit level    
    end
```

Comment: try with currentFolderDir =pwd

Comment: As commented, it is tried, and it did not work either.

<pre>
    entries = dir(currentFile);
    length(entries)
</pre>

shows '0' at the depth of the 2nd level which is not a correct behavior.

Comment: You don't add the directory to the files. You should be using `fullfile(currentFile,entries(i).name)` - otherwise matlab can not find the directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have adapted a function I use to recursively process files in certain directory. It correctly goes through all the subdirectories and shows the filenames, but it doesn't show the depthlevel, folderCount and fileCount. It should be easy to adapt, but if you need help just let me know :

```
function processDirectory(path)

if ~strcmp(path(end), filesep)
    path(end+1)=filesep;
end
dirInfo= dir(path);
files=~[dirInfo.isdir];
fileNames={dirInfo(files).name};
disp(path);
if ~isempty(fileNames)
    for i=1:length(fileNames)
        % Do whathever (show file names?)
        disp(fileNames(i));
    end
end

% For each subdir, call itself again
isDir=[dirInfo.isdir];
dirNames={dirInfo(isDir).name};
dirNames(strcmp(dirNames, '.') | strcmp(dirNames, '..'))=[];

for i=1:length(dirNames)
    processDirectory([path dirNames{i} filesep]);    
end
```